# Java Recursion Confusion. Trying to get files in a directory

Tags: java, recursion

My objective is to get the names of files in a Folder, and if that Folder has another folder inside, then it should further give me the names of files in THAT folder as well. And so on.

This is the code:

```
public class GettingDir {

public static void main(String[] args){
    File dir = new File("Numbers/");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for(File f : files){
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println(f.getName());

            getDirectory(f.toString());
        }else{
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }

    }

    }
```

And here's the getDirectory() method:

```
public static void getDirectory(String dir){
    File place = new File(dir);
    if(place.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = place.listFiles();
        for(File f : files){
            if(f.isDirectory()){
                System.out.println(f.getName());
                getDirectory(dir);
            }else{
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now. I don't completely understand the error, Its an infinite loop and then infinite errors. Can some brilliant mind tell me what's wrong?

P.S. Sorry if the code is pathetic, I'm a beginner :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a small mistake: `getDirectory(dir)` should be replaced by `getDirectory(f.toString())`. On top of that, you can simplify your main method.

```
public static void getDirectory(String dir){
    File place = new File(dir);
    if(place.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = place.listFiles();
        for(File f : files){
            if(f.isDirectory()){
                System.out.println(f.getName());
                getDirectory(f.toString());
            } else{
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    getDirectory("Numbers/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the recursive function you should call `getDirectory(f);` instead of `getDirectory(dir);`

In your implementation you actually start again at the first level. The stack will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the *name* of the directory to the getDirectory() method, and this methods just uses `new File(dir)` to get a File. So it doesn't start from its parent directory, but from the user directory, always. Use File objects to represent Files:

In the main method:

```
getDirectory(f);
```

And in the getDirectory method:

```
public static void getDirectory(File place){
    File[] files = place.listFiles();
    for(File f : files){
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println(f.getName());
            getDirectory(f);
        } else {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the main method could be redurced to

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    File dir = new File("Numbers/");
    getDirectory(dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from being a brilliant mind, but you should change

```
getDirectory(dir);
```

to

```
getDirectory(f.toString());
```

in your `getDirectory` method

```
public static void getDirectory(String dir) {
    File place = new File(dir);
    if (place.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = place.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(f.getName());
                getDirectory(f.toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, just a hint, you can further simplify your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getDirectory("Numbers/");
}

public static void getDirectory(String dir) {
    File place = new File(dir);
    System.out.println(dir);
    if (place.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = place.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) getDirectory(f.toString());
    }
}
```